# Oracle - No Data found error and a using query with NVL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

```
SELECT NVL(FIELD1,0),NVL(FIELD2,0)
    INTO var1, var2
    FROM TABLEONE
    WHERE SomeField_ID = 11111
    AND SomeOtherFieldID in (1,2)
    AND SomeStatusID in (250,360)
```

This is inside a trigger and I am getting no data found error. Shouldn't the `nvl` substitute 0 on both variables? How can I substitute 0 if the records are not found?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Ok, so I do a count and then if count is 0 then manually assign both the variables to 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a `no data found` because your query is not returning any rows, not because of the `nvl` invocation...

`nvl` will behave as you are correctly expecting:

```
if field1 == Null:
    return 0
else:
    return field1
```

Your `where` clause is probably filtering all rows.

```
WHERE SomeField_ID = 11111
AND SomeOtherFieldID in (1,2)
AND SomeStatusID in (250,360)
```

Comment: You can also use exceptions (to prevent doing an extra count).